# Why was this clearly constructive, seemingly on-topic question closed and locked?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, locked-posts, historical-lock

The question "[Converting the “arguments” object to an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/converting-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript)" is a very useful, frequently asked question. It asks a very precise, answerable question, and the answers are good and helpful. I see *no reason* that this should have been locked and closed as off-topic.

Why is this "not considered a good, on-topic question for this site"?

Comment: WTH did I just exactly now want to ask the very much same question?

Comment: @Bergi Probably because it was triggered by the same question in the javascript tag. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Because it is a code golfing question, and it is **not** on-topic here. He has working code, and he's merely asking for people to contribute other ways to do it. There is no real problem there and there are an infinite number of answers.

Comment: I disagree that it's a code golfing question. It asks for a good way to convert a JavaScript arguments object to an array. *This is an extremely reasonable thing to want to do concisely,* and the asker's version was clearly suboptimal. It's not the OP's fault that the "correct" solution is rather non-obvious.

Comment: The fact that it used to be tagged with [tag:code-golf] seems to contradict that.

Comment: A link to the [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/960866/1) may be helpful as the current version doesn't have that tag anymore.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be a good canonical question candidate. Can't we instead edit the question to remove the "*make this shorter*" part and put "*How to convert the arguments object to an array*" instead?

Comment: I didn't realize it was previously tagged code-golf, but that doesn't make it a bad question once the tag was removed. It still stands on its own without the tag.

Comment: OK, even if the question was off-topic, why was it locked down? To prevent it from deletion? To prevent reopen votes?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array) is basically asking a similar "how can I do this concisely" question. Would you call it a code golf question?

Comment: @AlexisKing its still in the 'too broad' category.  Look at the answers its getting... (poorly formatted) code dump, "To add to all the answers, printing the object as a JSON string is also an option.", "There's one additional way if your array is of type char[]:", "This does the job.".  It has the possibility of a basically endless stream of answers.

Comment: @Bergi As I was cleaning up the code-golf tag itself, many of them ones we kept got the historical lock. The locks were meant to tell people the question is not a good fit, not as much to prevent reopens/deletions.

Comment: @MichaelT The Java question I linked has 13 answers, and it's fine. Who cares? It wasn't like it was becoming a problem with people constantly answering this question. All popular questions inevitably get that kind of clutter in the answers.

Comment: @AlexisKing clutter in answers is *not* a good thing.  Poorly written answers are not a good thing either.  Questions that encourage clutter or poorly written answers not good questions either.

Comment: @MichaelT Some on-topic questions naturally encourage clutter in the answers. Just because some of the answers suck doesn't mean that the question isn't valid. Again, any question that's popular enough is going to attract lots of people to post trivial alternative answers.

Comment: @AlexisKing that would make it a good reason to close it as too broad if it attracts those answers.  If people aren't down voting and deleting or rewriting poorly written answers, the question should probably be locked to avoid the contentious reopen/reclose cycles.

Comment: @MichaelT [The second-highest voted question on SO has 25 answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git) [The third-highest has *30* answers!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit) Do you think we should close those, too? All of those answers have equally-trivial additional solutions.

Comment: @AlexisKing I am sure they have more if you could see deleted answers. Up votes do not mean in scope or not too broad.  They are an indication of popularity of a question or an answer.  That is orthogonal to the issue of is it a good StackOverflow format question.  Up votes do not measure "should it be closed".

Comment: @MichaelT I agree, but I'm just making the point that attracting bad answers doesn't make a *question* bad. The question we're arguing about is well within the scope of this site.

Comment: @Alexis I agree with you that this could possibly be transformed into a better question if you could establish *an actual problem*. The fact that he has working code and just wants a different way to do it makes it look very off-topic. Your Java example has an actual problem - they tried printing the Array object and it outputted gibberish. That's not the case here. *There is no real problem* other than his desire to have shorter code. That's the definition of code golfing.

Comment: @animuson Then do what Bergi suggested—unlock it and polish it into a canonical question/answer. It's linked to from all over the place already. Hell, I'd be willing to update it myself.

Comment: @Alexis Have at it.

Comment: @AlexisKing Make sure to flag answers that no longer match the modified question so that the mods can delete them (you might want to reference this meta post to make sure they are aware of the 'not just flagging things and there is reason to do it').

Answer (score 1):

When you ask the question "Why was this post closed," you should always ask the logically inferred question "Why should this post be reopened?"

Posts are reopened for three reasons:

1. The close reason is *clearly* invalid, or
2. The post needs more answers, and/or
3. The question has been improved, making it on-topic.

Of the three, the third reason is the most valid: the post has been improved, making it on-topic.

Bad questions have an impact on their answerability.  Certain questions have characteristics that make them spam or discussion magnets, so if a question is to be reopened (the principal purpose of which is to allow answering again), then question improvement is the best option, because it improves the chances of getting better answers.

**Worth noting:**  The post you cited has attracted a number of poor answers.  Since closing prevents answers from being posted, it also prevents bad answers and "me too" answers from being posted.  Again, the remedy is question improvement.